# Data Structure for strings on integers

Tags: data-structures, strings

Designing a datastructure which supports the following operations on integers (It can also be visualized as a datastructure on strings, if the alphabets/characters have total ordering)

Operations on the integer string.

1. Insert an element with value $v$ at index i.
2. Delete an element from index $i$
3. Increment value at index $i$ from $v$ to $v+1$.
4. Given an index $i$ and value $t$, find the index $j$ (if it exists) such that

   a. $j>i$

   b. value at index $j$ is $t$

   c. values of indices between $i$ and $j$ is not equal to $t$.

I understand that the operation #3, can be supported by operation #1 and #2, but I just mentioned it, to see if there is a slightly better way to do it.

I know a way to do this in $O(\lg n)$ time. I am looking for alternative solutions, which can be done in O(1) worst case or amortized time. I do not want to explain my answer, as it might hinder your natural thinking process(hint Young's tableau). I am stuck and unable to think of an alternative better solution because I know the answer which works in $O(\log n)$.

Example
suppose the string is

1 1 2 3 2 1 1 1 4.

If I want to insert 1 at index 4, right after the value 2, then the updated string would look like this.

1 1 2 **1** 3 2 **2** 1 1 4.

The 2 in bold was previously a 1, but it underwent operation #3 after insertion of value 1 at index 4.

Comment: There can many data-structures which will have different time complexities for different operations. You need to mention your requirement for each operation.

Comment: Do you have any partial solution for these and do you have a specific runnin-time requirement for the operations?

Comment: There is no need for ordering, you only test for equality.

Comment: What does it mean to *insert* a value at index $i$ ? What if you do this twice in a row ? What does it mean to delete from index $i$ ? What if you do this twice in a row ? What if there was never an insertion at $i$ ? ... As written, all this is meaningless.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, usually it means to shift elements $i, i+1, \ldots$ to the right and place the element into (now free) position $i$: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-int-E-

Comment: @Dmitry: I want to hear this from the OP.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, what Dmitry mentions it is exactly what I am implying. That is the usual interpretation. Otherwise, I would have mentioned to update the value at index $i$, instead of inserting the value at index $i$.

Comment: @Russel  I have a partial solution which works in O(\log n) time per operation which is quite straightforward. I am hesitant to reveal the solution, as I believe that giving the solution will negatively influence to follow that path and get trapped like I got trapped.

Comment: Information retention is bad practice on this site.

Comment: @YvesDaoust. The naive solution just uses a Young's tableau. If it helps.

All ones are in row 1 of YT.
all 2's in second row and so on.

Comment: As your data structure fills, the cells need to be somehow reorganized. This seems a harder problem than the original question. Unless you supply a detailed solution, I cannot agree with "just uses a Young's tableau".

Comment: I agree with your valuable thoughts. I will try to rephrase the question properly and post it again. Thank you Mr Yves. Even though we didn't arrive at the solution I desired, you comments have given me valuable insight and helped me find the flaw in my thinking.
Thanks a ton :D.

Answer (score 0):

There should be solution based on a weight balanced binary tree such that every node keeps its weight (number of descendants). For an insertion or deletion, you will find the $i^{\text{th}}$ node using the weight information. Then perform standard insertion or deletion.

The increment operation is trivial.

The search operation can be implemented as a modified search, where you disregard the first $i$ nodes.

Comment: I have added more details to the question, which other had requested.
Hope that helps you find an even better solution

Comment: @Vk1: you did not care to address the very first comment to your post. So "even better" makes no sense.

Comment: I mentioned in the question description, that I looking for a solution which takes O(1) time for these operations worst case/amortized.

Comment: @Vk1: the comment said *per operation*. All operations in $O(1)$ seems unrealistic.